# What does this code mean: "print >> sys.stderr"

Tags: python, syntax

```
print >> sys.stderr, "Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:"
```

Why print '>>' in front of `sys.stderr`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This syntax means writes to a file object (`sys.stderr` in this case) instead of standard output. [[Link]](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print)

In Python 3.0, `print` becomes a function instead of a statement: [[Link]](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print)

```
print("Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Note that this is Python 2.x syntax.  Python 3.0 has print as a function, and redirection is done completely differently.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html):

> print also has an extended form,
>   defined by the second portion of the
>   syntax described above. This form is
>   sometimes referred to as “print
>   chevron.” In this form, the first
>   expression after the >> must evaluate
>   to a “file-like” object, specifically
>   an object that has a write() method as
>   described above. With this extended
>   form, the subsequent expressions are
>   printed to this file object. If the
>   first expression evaluates to None,
>   then sys.stdout is used as the file
>   for output.