# Python operator ">>"

Tags: python, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - '>>' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411749/python-operator)

What does the >> operator means in Python?
ie:

```
x = x + str(n%2)
n >> 1
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest an internet search for `python operators` and clicking on the first hit.

Comment: [Bitwise shift right](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)

Comment: This is the complete list: http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: Here's a convenient link to further reading about what bit shifting is/does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Bit_shifts

Comment: @aganders3 - note that the OP didn't know what the operator did, so the bit shift wiki would not have been helpful -- other than as a side door answer to the question :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm, understood, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but a comment. There were plenty of "It's a bit shift operator, it shifts your bits." answers already posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n >> 1` shifts `n` right `1` bit. This is the same as dividing by 2.

More generally, `n >> m` shifts `n` right `m` bits, giving a division by 2^m.

#### See also:

- [Shifting operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) in Python's documentation
- [Logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, note that there's a completely different usage which is changing the stream that `print` uses by default:

```
print >> sys.stderr, message
```

For more information, please have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1987626/183066).

Answer (score 0):

That's the [right shift](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's the bitshift operator:

```
x >> n
```

x shifted right by n bits.