# Python, adding a file into another file

Tags: python, overwrite

I have to define a function: `save_file(filename, new_list)` which takes a file name and a new list and writes that list to the file in the correct format.

So, for example,

```
save_file(’file.txt’, load_file(’file.txt’))
```

(`load_file` is a predefined function which opens and reads the file)

should overwrite the new list with exactly the same content.

I have no clue how to go about this, any ideas?

The load_file function seems to work but can't seem to get the save_file function working.

This is what I have so far:

I have this so far:

```
def load_file(filename):
f = open(filename, 'Ur')
 for line in f:
    print line

f.close()

def save_file(filename, new_list):
with open(new_list, 'Ur') as f1:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
```

Comment: what is "the correct format"? What are your requirements? What did you try so far?

Comment: What's the content of the list? Do you need to recover the list in python from the file later?

Comment: os.system("cat file1 file2 > file3")

Comment: @glglgl I'm not sure what correct format is supposed to mean, those were the only instructions I was given.

Comment: @Diego Herranz the content of the list is a list of names. And the list will be used again and added to later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `new_list` is clearly a list of lines, not a filename, you don't need all the stuff with `open`ing and `read`ing it. And you also can't do saving in a single `write`.

But you can do it *almost* that simply.

You didn't specify whether the lines in `new_list` still have their newlines. Let's first assume they do. So, all you have to do is:

```
def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(new_list))
```

… or …:

```
def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(new_list)
```

But your teacher may be expecting something like this:

```
def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in new_list:
            f.write(line)
```

What if the newlines were stripped off, so we have to add them back? Then things are a bit more complicated the first two ways, but still very easy the third way:

```
def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(new_list) + '\n')

def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(line + '\n' for line in new_list)

def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in new_list:
            f.write(line + '\n')
```

---

Meanwhile, you have *not* gotten `load_file` to work. It's supposed to return a list of lines, but it doesn't return anything (or, rather, it returns `None`). `print`ing something just prints it out for the user to see, it doesn't store anything for later use.

You want something like this:

```
def load_file(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
    return lines
```

However, there's a much simpler way to write this. If you can do `for line in f:`, then `f` is some kind of iterable. It's almost the same thing as a list—and if you want to make it into an actual list, that's trivial:

```
def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        return list(f)
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this error a lot
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Have tried each method you have suggested but still now working. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @EdenMaynard: That's because, as I said at the bottom, you don't have `load_file` right either. It's supposed to return a list of lines (or _something_), but it doesn't, it just prints out those lines and returns `None`. You can't save it to a file because you don't have anything to save to a file.

Comment: I have used the first code for load_file. When I try to use save_file, the original file gets everything deleted and I get an error saying: filename.write('\n'.join(new_list) + '\n')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: @EdenMaynard: Sorry, stupid typo on my part. All those `filename.write` (and `filename.writelines` and so on) should be `f.write`. I fixed it; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time and help. Finally got it to work. Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: awesome answer I have to say it!

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_file(filename, new_list):
    with open(new_list, 'r') as a:
        with open(filename, 'w') as b:
            b.write(a.read())
```

Just a small adjustment to SaltChicken's answer.

Comment: I have tried this and SaltChicken's and keep getting this error: with open(new_list, 'r') as f1:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Comment: Since this is just a small adjustment to SaltChicken's answer, it has the same problem. `new_list` is a list of lines, not a filename.

Comment: @abarnert the new_list is simply another file with a new list in it.

Comment: @EdenMaynard: If that's true, then `save_file(filename, load_file(filename))` can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print >>` to make it simply :

```
>>> with open('/src/file', 'r') as f1, open('/dst/file', 'w') as f2:
...      print >> f2, f1.read()
```

Inspired from [What does this code mean: "print >> sys.stderr"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987626/what-does-this-code-mean-print-sys-stderr).